# She reasoned that she must be/have been or had to be?

Tags: sequence-of-tenses

> She reasoned that she (must be) (must have been) (had to be) a victim of sex discrimination.

I think the first option is okay, but the tenses confuse me here: she reasoned in the past that she was a victim at the moment in the past when she reasoned. Another way would be to say: "She reasoned she was a victim." However, there is no uncertainty in this sentence, the sentence renders the meaning as "she was sure she was."

Comment: They are all correct, and have nearly the same meaning. The only difference is "must be" and "had to be" mean that at the moment of reasoning she was a victim. "must have been" means she was a victim first, then reasoned she was a victim later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Examples 1 & 3:

She reasoned that she **must be / had to be** a victim of sex discrimination.

The meaning is the same. She concludes that she is still a victim of sex discrimination:

Illustration: She applied for a promotion for which she was the best qualified candidate. But the job went to a man with less experience and few qualifications. She didn't get the job.

**She reasoned that she must be/had to be a victim of sex discrimination.** That's the only plausible explanation for her failure to get the job.

Example 2:

She reasoned that she **must have been** a victim of sex discrimination. Here she concludes that at some point in the past, she must have been a victim of sex discrimination.

Illustration: Because she didn't get the job she deserved, she resigned and joined another company where her talents were recognised and she was promoted.

**When she reflected, she reasoned that she **must have been** a victim of sex discrimination in her former employment.** Otherwise, she would have got the job.

Answer (score 1):

- Linda reasoned that Jane must be a victim of sex discrimination.

Jane is currently a victim of sex discrimination.

- Linda reasoned that Jane must have been a victim of sex discrimination.

Logic tells us with certainty that Jane was a victim of sex discrimination at some point in the past.

- Linda reasoned that Jane had to be a victim of sex discrimination.

Logic tells us with strong certainty that Jane is currently a victim of sex discrimination.

Another possible meaning for "had to be" is related to planning. Linda is a dishonest politician planning to run for office.

- Jane was working for the opposition candidate, a man, but was willing to help Linda win. But how could Linda explain her friend switching sides, and how could Jane help Linda win? *Linda reasoned that Jane had to be a victim of sex discrimination.*